# Puppet master wont allow sign puppet agent certificate request, saying "Could not resolve x.x.x.x: no name for x.x.x.x

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, dns, puppet, devops

I have a puppet-master puppet agent setup in AWS VPC. The system has been running for the last 2 years without too many issues, but today the master will not accept a certificate request from any of the agents once they are launched saying `"Could not resolve x.x.x.x: no name for x.x.x.x"`

The puppet master is specified in the puppet.conf for the agent. I can see in the logs for the master that the agent does in face reach, but the master "rejects" and does not sign a certificate from an instance in a subnet which it usually accepts. Ive also tried to remove the certs from the master running "puppet cert clean ip-x-x-x-x.ap-in..." and re trying manually from the agent. The agent tries to connect and then says `"Exiting;no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled"`

Comment: you are probably not runing `puppet agent -t` with `root`. Before your run, don't forget to stop `puppet` service, remove `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl` directory. After you run `puppet agent -t`, you can start the service.

Comment: Unfortunately I am doing this. When the instances launch they have a predefined script which creates a puppet.conf, install puppet and then runs puppet agent -t to a predefined puppet master. Its always worked (as in for the last year), now its suddenly broken.

Comment: and with what user are you running `puppet agent -t`? can you do `sudo su -` to become `root` and run `puppet agent -t`?

Comment: Running as root, when I run puppet agent -t, `"Exiting;no certificate found and waitforcert is disabled"` i get this. It seems like a DNS issue, I dont understand why but when the puppet master receives a request from the agent it cannot resolve the IP of the child.

Answer (score 0):

Being on `ec2`, I presume is Linux.

1. Stop `puppet` service:

   - `systemctl stop puppet pxp-agent` (on `systemd` OS-es) or
   - `service puppet stop` (on `init.d` OS-es)
2. Remove `/etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl`
3. Run `puppet agent -t --debug` manual. In this case the `ssl` directory should be created. You shouldn't be getting any errors (due to connectivity)
4. Start `puppet` service:

   - `systemctl start puppet pxp-agent` (on `systemd` OS-es) or
   - `service puppet start` (on `init.d` OS-es)

Run `puppet agent -t` also on the master(s), as you may want to check that your certs are Ok on the Primary Master (CA) (and/or Compile Masters)